# In safe mode, main monitor turns off after c5 minutes and won't wake

Tags: display, sleep, safe-mode, amd-graphics-card, dell-dimension

In Windows safe modes (all 3) main monitor turns off after c5 minutes and can't be woken up by keyboard or mouse. The monitor works fine when the PC normally booted.

The monitor screen message is "Entering Power Save mode". Pushing buttons on the monitor to enter settings gives the message "There is no signal coming from your computer". A fan in the PC builds up speed during the safe mode boot and then continues to run at high speed even after the monitor turns off.

This fault also happens when booted:

1. into the windows recovery environment from F8
2. from a Windows repair CD, and
3. from an AV scanner CD. (In the repair CD I chose to take drivers from the PC and the command line option. I am not sure what drivers the AV scanner CD uses).

But NOT: 
1. when booted from F8 using the low resolution (VGA) option.

My system is a Dell 8300 with an AMD Radeon HD 6770 series graphics card (AMD Radeon HD 5770 chipset) and a U2412M monitor connected using a DVI cable. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 and Comodo CCAV security software. The computer is **not** set to turn off its monitor or PCI bus to save power. (I cannot find a power saving setting for the card. I guess it does not have one.).

My only thought so far is that maybe the graphics card is not working with the Windows graphics drivers which are used in safe mode. Perhaps in low resolution mode the AMD drivers are used at low resolution instead of the Windows drivers, so avoiding the problem. I am not sure how to check this, or correct the problem.

This is quite mystifying and is preventing me from running testing tools to fix a deeper stability problem on the system, so I would really appreciate any help people can give.

Kind regards and many thanks.

Mouse

Comment: Hello, have you tried another monitor? The frequency might be off in Safe Mode, so the monitor thinks there's nothing there.

Comment: Good thought, thanks. No I have not yet. I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: Edited post to add that a fan in the PC runs at high speed during the safe mode boot and after the monitor turns off.

Comment: I tried another monitor, but it did not work unfortunately. Thanks very much for the suggestion though. The monitor was from the same maker (Dell), connected using the same interface, but was a different resolution, vintage and range. Unfortunately I don't have a third monitor. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You said "The computer is not set to turn off its monitor or PCI bus to save power." Turn this off, if you need to save power __turn off the monitor__ instead. Yes Windows 7 loads only needed drivers in Safe Mode and reverts to VGA driver(s).

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Maybe I am misundersanding your response, if not I think you might have missed the "not" in my post? I have edited the post now to make sure it is clear.

Comment: Also thanks vssher for confirming only VGA drivers are used in safe mode - that is very helpful.

Comment: I have also added to my post a note to say I could not find any power saving options for the graphics card in windows power settings. I guess Window 7 does not have any?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if updating the AMD graphics card drivers may resolve the issue?

My dexisting river version is quite old and seems to be an OEM one: Date=19-Apr-2011, AMD Driver Package Version=8.85-110419a-115704C-Dell, Driver Version: 8.850.0.0.

Regarding new versions the Dell web site (based on machine service tag) offers me: version 8.85, A01, last updated date: 12 Dec 2013. Windows update offers me:an unstated version, published in 13/09/15 but released July 2015, covering WDDM (Windows Driver Model) 2.0, which I can get no further info on via the normal links presumably due to withdrawal of support for Windows 7. Slightly worried about this latter version as on Windows Update **catalogue** the only 2015 and WDDM2.0 releases for 6700/6770 series cards I can find are not for Windows 7. AMD Offers me, for the AMD Radeon HD 6770 and Window 7 x64, catalyst software (which i think includes the driver) version 15.7.1 WHQL, dated 29/07/2015 plus Radeon Software Crimson Editions Beta (Crimson Beta probably to be avoided?)

So pretty confusing!

Initially I thought I should not update the driver as:

1. I suspected the drivers were not loaded in safe mode. (Now confirmed).
2. I did not want to risk a such a deep update on an unstable system unless it was likely to help

But I just found this post: [Updating graphics card firmware](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/9blr9e/can_gpu_firmware_be_updated_like_other_hardwares/), which says that in the case of AMD cards, firmware updates are supplied via driver updates.

Might this solve the problem? For the reasons given above I don't want to try it if there is no, or only a small, chance.

Comment: Added available driver updates.

Comment: Just notice that new drivers of Windows update site though published September 2015 were released July 215, so updated the post with this information. I guess that means that the Windows update and AMD releases are likely the same.